# Global sections of higher direct image sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-surfaces

Let $X$ be a regular projective (complex) surface and $S$ be a finite set of closed points on $X$. Denote by $j:X\backslash S \to X$ the open immersion. Assume further that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$. Is $H^0(R^1j_*\mathcal{O}_{X \backslash S})=0$?

Comment: Is there any reason to believe something like this should be true? I don't see why there should be any natural map between the two and it's false for $S$ empty...

Comment: @dhy I have edited the question.

Comment: $j_*\mathcal{O}_{X\smallsetminus S}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X$.

Comment: @abx I am a bit confused. I know this fact. I do not understand, whether this proves or disproves the question. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: $R^1j_*\mathcal{O}_{X\smallsetminus S}$ is a sheaf supported on $S$, with fiber at $s\in S$ the group $H^2_{\{s\} }(\mathcal{O}_X)$, which is nonzero. See SGA2, §I and II.

Comment: But that is not enough to answer the question since $H^0(X-S,R^1 j_*\mathcal{O}_{X-S}) = Ker[H^0(X-S,R^2j_*\mathcal{O}_{X-S}) \rightarrow H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $S$ is finite, $X$ being projective is a red herring, so is anything about the (global) cohomology of $\mathscr O_X$, and 
(to some extent) it being a surface,  or regular.

If $X$ is $S_2$, and $\dim X\geq 2$, then the sheaf version of Exercise III.2.3 in [Hartshorne] (or the exercise itself noting that by $S$ being finite one may start with restricting to affine schemes) implies that there is a long exact sequence
$$
0\to \mathscr H_S^0(\mathscr O_X) \to \mathscr O_X \to j_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S} \to \mathscr H_S^1(\mathscr O_X) \to \\ \to \mathscr H_{\emptyset}^1(\mathscr O_X)  \to R^1j_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S} \to \mathscr H_S^2(\mathscr O_X)  \to \mathscr H_{\emptyset}^2(\mathscr O_X) \to \dots
$$
Since $X$ is $S_2$, $\mathscr H_S^0(\mathscr O_X)  =\mathscr H_S^1(\mathscr O_X) =0$ and $\mathscr H_{\emptyset}^i(\mathscr O_X) =0$ for all $i>0$, so this falls apart to the isomorphisms
$$
j_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S}\simeq \mathscr O_X
$$
and
$$
R^ij_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S} \to \mathscr H_S^{i+1}(\mathscr O_X)
$$
for all $i>0$. (In particular $R^ij_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S}$ is supported on $S$). 
Since $S$ is finite, $R^ij_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S}$ is the sheaf associated ot its own global sections, in particular $R^ij_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S}\neq 0$ if and only if $H^0(X,R^ij_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S})\neq 0$.

By Grothendieck vanishing $H_x^{d}(\mathscr O_X)\neq 0$ for $d=\dim   \mathscr O_{X,x}$ for any $x\in X$, which shows    that if $\dim X=d$ near $S$ (e.g., $X$ is equidimensional, or at least that the dimension of the union of irreducible components of $X$ containing $S$ is $d$), then $H^0(X,R^{d-1}j_*\mathscr O_{X\setminus S})\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed and helpful answer. I also wanted to ask, does this also mean $H^1(\mathcal{O}_{X\backslash S}) \not-0$?

Comment: Yes. It's the same as $H^0$ of $R^1$. You should be able to extract this from the above proof.